# How to convert in site spectra to satellite spectra?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, convolution, conversion, physical-units

I want to convert the in situ reflectance into satellite reflectance using SRF (Spectral response function). I have downloaded the SRF file but I find that the bands wavelengths are different than in the Sentinel 2 handbook.
For example, in the handbook, the wavelength of band 1 is $443\,\mathrm{nm}$, while in the SRF, band 1 starts at $412\,\mathrm{nm}$ for S2A.

My question is: if I want to convert my in-situ data to satellite data, do I need to start from $443\,\mathrm{nm}$ or from $412\,\mathrm{nm}$ as in the SRF file?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. While I guess there's some satellite experts for whom this is clear, it would be good if you could write out what the abbreviations SRF, S2, S2A, B1 mean.

Comment: If there are files/data that you feel would help someone investigate this for you, you should include it (you mention an excel file?).
As Marcus said, you also need to re-formulate your question (I tried doing that for you) into something comprehensible to non-satellite experts.
It seems you're asking about differences between two *standard* sources (SRF vs S2) for band wavelengths, in which case I'd ask, have you researched which source is mostly used in the field or in scientific publications?

Comment: The same question has been asked there [In situ reflectance to satellite reflectance](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/in-situ-reflectance-to-satellite-reflectance/37097)